# How to make a multi-color seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dictionary with key value pairs:

```
COLORS= {'fish':'blue','tigers':'orange'}
```

and data:

```
  team  value  
0 fish   20
1 fish   15
2 fish   10
3 tigers 7
4 tigers 13
5 tigers 15
```

I would like to make a lineplot and use the `.get()` method to get the color of each team and color the line plot accordingly (first three half of the line would be blue, last half orange)

I tried using the following code:

```
sns.lineplot(data = df, x = np.arange(len(df)), y = value, color=COLORS.get(df.team)
```

But I get the error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I can get it to work with the following code

```
...color=COLORS[df.team.iloc[0]]
```

But that makes the whole lineplot the first color that appears, which in this case would be blue. Again, I want to color the lineplot according to `team`, and I am not sure why `.get()` isn't working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get()` doesn't work because you are calling it on a `dictionary` object but passing `pandas.Series` object.

It will work if you pass a single value that you are searching for. ( See this [article](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#dgetkey-default) if you need further explanation )
Which you did by passing `COLORS[df.team.iloc[0]]` but it only passes a single value i.e. the first team and that's why you get the whole plot in one color.

I would group DataFrame by team, then iterate over grouped DataFrame and draw a new line for each team. Now you can use `.get()` function on `COLORS` dictionary and get correct color.

See if this helps you:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
gk = df.groupby("team")
x = np.arange(len(df))
index = 0
for team_name, team_group in gk:
    sns.lineplot(
        x=x[index : index + len(team_group)],
        y=team_group.value,
        color=COLORS.get(team_name),
    )
    index += len(team_group)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value'`

Comment: @bismo If your df looks the same as you mentioned. It should have `value` column. I used this as data, based on your question.
`data = {"team": ["fish", "fish", "fish", "tigers", "tigers", "tigers"], "value": [20, 15, 10, 7, 13, 15]}`